# I've installed django on dreamhost using passenger_wsgi now how do I export my development project onto this?

Tags: django

I followed the wiki on http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django .
Django is installed in my site's directory and I've even created my first project, now what do I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your project files to the server and transfer your database to the sql server on dreamhost. Don't forget to make changes in your settings.py to reflect the environment. Should work otherwise me thinks.

Comment: Hey so if I copy my files through FTP into the project directory on dreamhost and then after configuring settings run the syncdb, the tables will be created ? and also Thanks a lot man for answering.